# Create an overlay (with bg image) over a div that is scrollable but don't scroll image

Tags: css, overlay

I have this fiddle for reference that shows what i'm talking about...when you scroll the table of data within the div, the image scrolls as well. I need the image to not move while the below div is scrolled, but I cannot do it. The div that overlays could be any size and I would also need the overlayed image to be in the correct spot even if the window was resized. I suppose that if it can't be done with CSS then a javascript solution would suffice, but would of course much rather have css only.

thanks!!!!

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ts46235/BMKZa/26/

css:

```
    div.overlay { 
      position: relative;
    }
    div.overlay:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: url(https://www.fadingred.com/media/images/spinner-small.gif) no-repeat 50% 50% ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to move the `overlay` class property to a div containing your `grid` div (as an example your `float-left clear-left` div), so that the gif image do not scroll with the your table.
Then, you need to adapt your CSS code like this :

```
div.overlay:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(https://www.fadingred.com/media/images/spinner-small.gif) no-repeat 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The deal is that with `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` property, we create a box the same size as your `grid` div and at the same position. Then, with `:before` rather than `:after`, the image is display on top of the content of the table rather than behind. And finally `pointer-events: none` ensures that the image won't cause trouble when selecting text.

Here is a working Fiddle : [( Fiddle )](http://fiddle.jshell.net/TdNgR/2/)

---

What I first suggested but didn't work as you wanted was :

```
div.overlay { 
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://www.fadingred.com/media/images/spinner-small.gif) no-repeat 50% 50% ;
}
div.overlay:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'll have to update the example, but this wont work when a row has a background on it...thats why we need the div overlay with a bg image so that it will always be on top of the below div

Comment: see sample of your solution here (the spinner is getting hidden and it still scrolls) http://fiddle.jshell.net/ts46235/BMKZa/25/

Comment: @ManOfSteele I see what you want now. I managed to do it, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for! (I had tried that but left out the height/width so i couldn't get it). Thank You @Levans

Comment: One additional requirement though, If I dont know the width/height of the containing div until runtime, is possible to set width/height later? I think that you cannot do that and in order to do it I would probably need to use a real <div> and not the :before pseudo element so I can grab it via jquery

Comment: @ManOfSteele I'm not a lot into JQuery, but it seems you cannot grab pseudo-elements such as `:before`. But you need it to have the image displayed on top of the table. Maybe you can do it with an `<img />` with absolute position and correct Z-index.

Comment: <code> div.overlaid { 
   position: relative;
 }
 div.spinnerOverlay {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 730px;
   height: 400px;
   background: url(/content/images/spinner.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
   /* Allows the overlaid div to still be selectable: */
   pointer-events: none;
 }</code>

Comment: all i did was instead of using pseudo element, i stuck a div as last child of the div.overlaid and was able to set the height/width after the fact by targeting that child element